# Volley network request response does not have HTML tags

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley for all the network requests, but it does not return most of the HTML tags in response. Example:

I need the response as :

```
{
    "id": "9407159",
    "jJ": "<mark class='highlighted'>Java</mark> Project Internship",
    "jRrl": null,
    "jCD": null,
    "jCNe": "Sparkcoders",
    "jD": 681901,
    "jL": ["Junagarh", "Gandhinagar", "Gandhidham", "Rajkot", "Bhuj", "Anand", "Bhavnagar", "Vadodara", "Mehsana", "Ahmedabad"],
    "jPe": "2018-10-23T00:00:00",
    "jCpe": true,
    "jKd": null,
    "jp": "0 to 2 Yrs",
    "jKs": "",
    "jR": 1,
    "jTe": 1,
    "jWC": "",
    "jWL": null,
    "jWD": null,
    "jEe": "2019-01-21T00:00:00",
    "jPJ": 0,
    "jHJ": 1
}
```

But I am not getting () HTML tag.

My code:

```
  @Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {

        // Volley does not handle null properly, so implement null response
        // check

        Log.d("RESPONSE code ","res "+response.statusCode);
        if (response.data.length == 0) {
            byte[] responseData = "{}".getBytes("UTF8");
            response = new NetworkResponse(response.statusCode,
                    responseData, response.headers, response.notModified);
        }


        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

        Log.d("Volley::GsonReq", "JsonResponse: " + jsonString);


        T parseObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);


        return Response.success(
                parseObject,
                parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(response));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("VolleyQueue: Encoding Error for " + getTag()
                + " (" + getSequence() + ")");
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("VolleyQueue: Fatal Error for " + getTag()
                + " (" + getSequence() + ")");
        return Response.error(new VolleyError(e));
    }
}
```

I have tried JSONObjectRequest and string request both. But both does not seem to work. jsonString variable doesnot have any HTML tags. I get  tags though whenever present but not other tag.

Not able to find a reason for it. Any solutions?

Comment: Please be more specific what error you are facing & also what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you share what is the response you getting form Volley?

Comment: updated the question @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: @SaiPrasad the response is same if you just ignore <mark tag.